# Advanced.aspx Search page not availbale

Tags: application-pages

Could anyone of you help me in enabling the `Advanced.aspx` page or provide me the Advanced.aspx page to load in `"/SitePages"` section in my website?

I am running SharePoint foundation 2013.

Comment: The advanced search features is not part of the Foundation license